# Recursive method to find value in linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, find, singly-linked-list

```
template<class Type>
int StringList<Type>::find(Type value)
{
int count = 0;

// Start of linked list
Node<Type> *current = head;

// Traverse list until end (NULL)
while (current != NULL)
{
    // Increase counter if found
    if (current->data == value)
    {
        count++;
    }

    // If not, move to the next node
    current = current->next;
}

cout << value << " was found " << count << " times" << endl;

return 0;





// same function but using Recursive method





// Start of linked list
Node<Type> *current = head;
int count = 0;

// Thinking this is the base case, since its similar to the while loop
if (current == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

// same as the while loop, finding the value increase the count, or in this case just prints to console
if ((current->data == value))
{
    cout << "Found match" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{   // If it didnt find a match, move the list forward and call the function again
    current = current->next;
    return find(value);
}

}
```

the function is supposed to find the value searched and return how many times that certain value was in the linked list.

how can I turn the first method, which uses a while loop, into something that does the same thing but uses recursion?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, scroll down

Comment: Looks like you are most of the way there, but I don't think you want to return immediately when you find a match. Instead, keep going until null and have each iteration return the number found so far.

Comment: Hmm that sounds great

Answer (score 0):

In order to use recursion, you will need to change the signature of your find function (or add a new function with the different signature) to take a node pointer as a parameter:

```
template<class Type>
int StringList<Type>::find(Type value, Node<Type> *where)
{
    if (where != nullptr)
    {
    // Do things
    }
}
```

Then, when you traverse the list, you pass `where->next` to the function. Once you hit the end of the list, with a `nullptr` value, the stack unrolls.

A key aspect of recursion as that the function or method being used only has to process a single node of your container. It then calls itself with the next node to be processed until there are no more nodes. In order to make this work, that function needs the node to process as a parameter, which is where your current code runs into problems.

Keep in mind that the elegance and simplicity of recursion is not free. Every call that a method makes to itself eats up stack, so a sufficiently large container can result in a crash if the stack for your process is depleted.

Comment: ok i see what youre saying , but at what part would i call the function again?

Comment: @LearningCode if you changes the function signature of your method to include a pointer to a node, you could use the function described in Vlad's answer directly. His second method, made public, does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For starters instead of the return type `int` it is better to use an unsigned type like for example `size_t`

You can use the following approach. Define two methods. The first one is a public non-static method `find` defined like

```
template<class Type>
size_t StringList<Type>::find( const Type &value ) const
{
    return find( head, value );
}
```

The second one is a private static method with two parameters defined like

```
template<class Type>
static size_t StringList<Type>::find( Node<Type> *current, const Type &value )
{
    return current == nullptr ? 0 : ( current->data == value ) + find( current->next, value );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using just one method ?

Comment: @LearningCode You can define the static method and use it though it is more natural to define two methods as I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I turn the first method, which uses a while loop, into
>   something that does the same thing but uses recursion?

The following would be closer to what you want.  You really should provide an [MCVE] ... the lack of which forces many guesses and assumptions about your code.

```
// It looks like StringList is a class (I ignored template issues), 
// and it appears that your class holds 'anchors' such as head
//   StringList is probably the public interface.
//   
// To find and count a targetValue, the code starts 
//   at the head node, and recurses through the node list.
// I would make the following a public method.
//
int StringList::findAndCountTargetValue(int targetValue)
   {
      int retVal = 0;

      if (nullptr != head)          // exists elements to search?
         retVal = head->countTV(targetValue); // recurse the nodes

      // else no match is possible

      return(retVal);
   }


// visit each node in the list 
int Node::countTV(const int targetValue)
   {
      int retVal = 0;  // init the count

      if (data != targetValue)  // no match
      {
         if(nullptr != next)            // more elements?
            retVal += next->countTV()   // continue recursive count
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << "Found match" << std::endl;   // for diag only

         retVal += 1; // because 1 match has been found

         if(nullptr != next)           // more elments
            retVal += next->countTV(); // continue recursive count
      }

      return (retVal);  // always return value from each level
   }
```